# In Rails, how do I change the color of borders on three separate pages with the click of a button on one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails application I have a page where there are several "proposals". I need a way where I can go in and select the "winning proposal". Then I want that proposal's div border color to change to green. The proposal also exists on three other pages so I would like to change its color in those places as well as the text in those divs. What's the best way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a field in a Proposal model that is a boolean, and indicates if it is winning or not. Have it default to false. Thats :default => false in the migration.

Then in your view, if the proposal is winning, you could give your div a class like .winning-proposal which would correspond to a CSS class you would put in proposal.css.scss or whatever is in your stylesheets directory. You would not include this class in the div if the Proposal not winning.

To set the winning proposal, you simply need to update attributes of the Proposal instance and set the winning boolean column for the model to true.

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: okay thanks, each proposal is tied to a project, so I'd like to change the color of a project's div to green if one of it's proposals was changed to "winning," so would I use something like <% if project.proposal.winning === true %>...use the div class .winning-proposal...?

Comment: If each Proposal has_one :project and each Project belongs_to :proposal, then you can certainly read the winning boolean through that association.

Comment: Also note, you do not need '=== true' because the value itself is a boolean, and therefore simply is true or false

Comment: Hmm, @project.proposals.winning doesn't seem to be working, can I not check the boolean value of a nested model in the parent's view?